# ngrx postpone an action in effect until another action is dispatched

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

Is it possible to postpone handling an action in effect until some other action is dispatched?
here the exact scenario:

1.dispatch action A1

2.effect handle A1 and request an http call

3.before http call is finished action B1 is dispatched

4.effect want to handle action B1 but it needs a part of store which is not ready until the "A1 http request" is completed

I handle it by a variable inside effect class, but I'm looking for a cleaner solution. here is my code

```
  numberOfDelaying=0;
  handleB1 = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions.pipe(
      ofType(DashboardActions.B1),
      withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(someSelector))),
      concatMap(([action, stateSlice]) => {
        //need the state slice which is not ready until A1 is completed
        if(!stateSlice && this.numberOfDelaying<10){ // here i check if the data is not ready dispatch B1 after 100 ms
          this.numberOfDelaying++;
          return of(DashboardActions.B1()).pipe(delay(100));
        }
        else if (stateSlice){
          // do some async call
        }
        else {
          return of(DashboardActions.Error())
        }

      })
    );
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

This could be a way to do it:

```js
handleB1 = createEffect(
  () => this.actions.pipe(
    ofType(DashboardActions.B1, DashboardActions.A1),
    pairwise(),
    switchMap(
      // Wait for `A1` to send the new state only if the prev action was `A1`
      ([prevAction, crtAction]) => 
        prevAction.type === DashboardActions.A1.type 
          ? this.store.pipe(
            select(someSelector), 
            skip(1) // Wait until the `A1` sends its new state
            first(),
            mapTo(crtAction)
          )
          : of(crtAction)
    )
    /* ... */
  )
)
```

You can give multiple actions to `ofType`: `ofType(DashboardActions.B1, DashboardActions.A1, ...),`.

As you mentioned, in `handleA1` you'll dispatch `B1` action before the http call is made. The `A1` action is also *intercepted* by `handleB1`, so when `B1` is dispatched from `handleA1`, in `handleB1` the pair `[prevAction, crtAction]` would be this: `[A1, B1]`.

Then, you're selecting the `A slice`, but you'll want to skip the existing state as it will be the old one and proceed only when the new state will arrive, which is when the asynchronous operation `handleA1` would've finished.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Tested on my flow and works great

Answer (score 0):

```
handleB1 = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions.pipe(
      ofType(DashboardActions.B1),
      withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(someSelector))),
      filter(([action, stateSlice]) => stateSlice.updated)
      ...
```

Your filter would look for some specific indication that the data has updated. Depending on the usage, if I need to know that something has completed I attach a token, a UUID for example, and watch for it in a filter. It could be included in B1 payload.

Would it work to dispatch B1 in the A1 effect? Something like this:

```
handleA1 = createEffect(() =>
   this.actions.pipe(
      ofType(DashboardActions.A1),
      mergeMap(action => apicall(action.payload)
           .pipe(
              map(resp => DashboardActions.B1),
              catchError(err => do something with error)
    )
)
)
```